# Missing right parenthesis error in query oracle

Tags: oracle

**Tables needed -**

**Habits**(conditionId, name)

**Patient**(patientId, name, gender, DoB, address, state,postcode, homePhone, businessPhone, maritalStatus, occupation, duration,unit, race, registrationDate , GPNo, NaturopathNo)

**PatientMetabolic** (functionNo, patientId, score)

**The Question Is** -

Question - Display the details of the patient (i.e. Name, Gender, Address, Postcode, DOB) who smokes and has the highest (most severe) total of metabolic functions.

(conditionid for smoke is H1 in Habit table)
(metabolic function are in patientbetabolic table functionNo)
(To find the highest most severe total of metabolic function we need to create a sum of score which tells who has the most metabolic functions)

**My query** -

```
SELECT * 
FROM patient 
where patientid IN (SELECT patientid,SUM(score) as totalscore 
                    from PATIENTMETABOLIC 
                    where patientid IN (SELECT patientid 
                                        from patienthabit 
                                        where conditionid = 'H1') 
                    group by patientid 
                    order by totalscore desc);
```

Error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: You've given us the error you got and the question you were asked to solve - but you haven't asked us a question. The query you've written is **really** bad - rather then trying to fix the error you should start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM PATIENT
  WHERE PATIENTID = (SELECT PATIENTID
                       FROM (SELECT patientid, SUM(score)
                               from PATIENTMETABOLIC 
                               where patientid IN (SELECT patientid
                                                     from patienthabit 
                                                     where conditionid = 'H1') 
                               group by patientid 
                               order by SUM(score) desc)
                       WHERE ROWNUM = 1);
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7988c6/1)

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to do this is by using joins.

```
select * from  (select  p.patientid,p.name,sum(pm.score) as total from patient p join patienthabit ph on p.patientid = ph.patientid
  and ph.conditionid = 'H1' Left join patientmetabolic pm 
  on p.patientid = pm.patientid  group by  p.patientid,p.name order by 3 desc) where ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the first inner query returns patientid and totalscore, you can't use it as a list against `IN` operator.

The result of this query might be similar to that of your query:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM patient p JOIN
     patienthabit ph ON p.patientid=ph.patientid
WHERE ph.conditionid='H1'
```